# AntPluginSampler in android application

Tags: android, kotlin, antplus

I m building an Android application using Kotlin. In this application I need to connect with a physical device throught bluetooth. This device implement Ant+ protocol. So I need to get from it

- Cadence value
- Speed value
- Fitness Equipment device.

These are three features that I can receive from it.

So I m building the following code:

```
  private fun setPanoramaChangeListener() {
                //some code
                setupAntSampler()
                //some code
            }
    
        private fun setupAntSampler() {
                bsdReleaseHandle = AntPlusBikeSpeedDistancePcc.requestAccess(
                    this, this,
                    mResultReceiver, mDeviceStateChangeReceiver
                )
        }
    
    var mResultReceiver: IPluginAccessResultReceiver<AntPlusBikeSpeedDistancePcc> =
            object :
                IPluginAccessResultReceiver<AntPlusBikeSpeedDistancePcc> {
                override fun onResultReceived(
                    result: AntPlusBikeSpeedDistancePcc?,
                    resultCode: RequestAccessResult?, initialDeviceState: DeviceState?
                ) {
                    when (resultCode) {
                        RequestAccessResult.SUCCESS -> {
                            HomeActivity.bsdPcc = result
                            //   tv_status.setText(result.deviceName + ": " + initialDeviceState)
                            subscribeToEvents()
                        }
                    }
                    releaseHandle = AntPlusFitnessEquipmentPcc.requestNewOpenAccess(
                        this@TourActivity,
                        this@TourActivity, mPluginAccessResultReceiver, mDeviceStateChangeReceiver,
                        mFitnessEquipmentStateReceiver
                    )
                }

 private fun subscribeToEvents() {
                bcPcc?.subscribeCalculatedCadenceEvent { _, _, calculatedCadence ->
                    runOnUiThread {
//                        binding?.tvCadence?.text = "Cadence value is : $calculatedCadence"

                        cadenceDoubleList.add(calculatedCadence.toDouble())
                        if (maxCadence < calculatedCadence.toDouble())
                            maxCadence = calculatedCadence.toDouble()
                        // tv_estTimestamp.setText(estTimestamp.toString())
                        //  tv_calculatedCadence.setText(calculatedCadence.toString())
                    }
                }
                bcPcc?.subscribeRawCadenceDataEvent { _, _, _, _ ->
                    runOnUiThread {
                        //   tv_estTimestamp.setText(estTimestamp.toString())
                        //  tv_timestampOfLastEvent.setText(timestampOfLastEvent.toString())
                        // tv_cumulativeRevolutions.setText(cumulativeRevolutions.toString())
                    }
                }
                if (bcPcc?.isSpeedAndCadenceCombinedSensor == true) {
                    runOnUiThread {

                        bsdReleaseHandle = AntPlusBikeSpeedDistancePcc.requestAccess(
                            this@TourActivity, bcPcc?.antDeviceNumber ?: 0, 0, true,
                            mResultReceiver, mDeviceStateChangeReceiver
                        )
                    }
                } else {
                    // Subscribe to the events available in the pure cadence profile
                    runOnUiThread {
                        //   tv_isSpdAndCadCombo.setText("No")
                        //    tv_calculatedSpeed.setText("N/A")
                    }
                    bcPcc?.subscribeCumulativeOperatingTimeEvent { _, _, _ ->
                        runOnUiThread {
                            //    tv_estTimestamp.setText(estTimestamp.toString())
                            //    tv_cumulativeOperatingTime.setText(cumulativeOperatingTime.toString())
                        }
                    }
                    bcPcc?.subscribeManufacturerAndSerialEvent { _, _, _, _ ->
                        runOnUiThread {
                            /* tv_estTimestamp.setText(estTimestamp.toString())
                             tv_manufacturerID.setText(manufacturerID.toString())
                             tv_serialNumber.setText(serialNumber.toString())*/
                        }
                    }
                    bcPcc?.subscribeVersionAndModelEvent { _, _, _, _, _ ->
                        runOnUiThread {
                            //  tv_estTimestamp.setText(estTimestamp.toString())
                            //  tv_hardwareVersion.setText(hardwareVersion.toString())
                            //  tv_softwareVersion.setText(softwareVersion.toString())
                            //   tv_modelNumber.setText(modelNumber.toString())
                        }
                    }
                    bcPcc?.subscribeBatteryStatusEvent { _, _, _, _ ->
                        runOnUiThread {
                            // tv_estTimestamp.setText(estTimestamp.toString())
                            // textView_BatteryVoltage.setText(if (batteryVoltage.toInt() != -1) batteryVoltage.toString() + "V" else "Invalid")
                            // textView_BatteryStatus.setText(batteryStatus.toString())
                        }
                    }
                    bcPcc?.subscribeMotionAndCadenceDataEvent { _, _, _ ->
                        runOnUiThread {
                            // tv_estTimestamp.setText(estTimestamp.toString())
                            //  textView_IsPedallingStopped.setText(isPedallingStopped.toString())
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

With the code I must select for 3 times my device.

There is a way to select automatically my device 1 time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To automate the device selection process in your Android application using Kotlin and the ANT+ protocol, you can modify your implementation to *store* the [device's ANT+ ID](https://www.thisisant.com/developer/resources/tech-faq/category/152/) after the first successful connection, using [`SharedPreferences`](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences).
Then, you would use this ID for subsequent connections to avoid manual selection each time.

```kotlin
// Assuming 'result' is the successful connection object and it contains the device ID
val deviceID = result.antDeviceNumber
// Store this device ID for future use
val sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("AntDevicePrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
with(sharedPref.edit()) {
    putInt("DeviceID", deviceID)
    apply()
}
```

Modify the `requestAccess` method calls to use the stored ANT+ ID for direct connection attempts.

```kotlin
val sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("AntDevicePrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
val storedDeviceID = sharedPref.getInt("DeviceID", -1) // -1 as default if not found

if (storedDeviceID != -1) {
    // Use storedDeviceID for direct connection
    bsdReleaseHandle = AntPlusBikeSpeedDistancePcc.requestAccess(
        this, storedDeviceID, 0, true,
        mResultReceiver, mDeviceStateChangeReceiver
    )
} else {
    // No stored device ID, proceed with regular discovery/connection process
    setupAntSampler()
}
```

You will need to integrate the device ID storage and retrieval logic in your `setupAntSampler` and `onResultReceived` methods. Make sure you handle cases where the device ID might change or when the direct connection attempt fails, prompting a fallback to the manual selection process.